# Using jquery to control form fields and form won't submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am using a simple script to enable and disable form fields based on a radio button selection.  I have used this script multiple times  and it works flawlessly.  When I complete the form selecting the first radio button and click on the submit button nothing happens. When I complete the form selecting the second radio button and click on the submit button it submits. The relevant part of the code is:

```
<li><input type="radio" name="pymt_details" id="pymt_details_1" value="pymt_details_1" required> 
Amount billed on <input type="text" name="pymt_details_1_a" id="pymt_details_1_a" style="width: 
80px" disabled> and amount billed on the <input type="text" name="pymt_details_1_b" id="pymt_details_1_b" 
style="width: 80px" disabled> day of each month</li>
            
<li><input type="radio" name="pymt_details" id="pymt_details_2" value="pymt_details_2"> <input 
type="text" name="pymt_details_2_a" id="pymt_details_2_a" style="width: 150px" disabled> on the <input 
type="text" name="pymt_details_2_b" id="pymt_details_2_b" style="width: 80px" disabled> and <input type="text" 
name="pymt_details_2_c" id="pymt_details_2_c" style="width: 150px" disabled> on the <input type="text" 
name="pymt_details_2_d" id="pymt_details_2_d" style="width: 80px" disabled> day of each month</li>

<input name="print" id="print" type="submit" value="Generate printable form" />
```

and the script is:

```
$("#pymt_details_1").click(function() {
  $("#pymt_details_1_a").prop("disabled",false);
  $("#pymt_details_1_b").prop("disabled",false);
  $("#pymt_details_2_a").prop("disabled",true);
  $("#pymt_details_2_b").prop("disabled",true);
  $("#pymt_details_2_c").prop("disabled",true);
  $("#pymt_details_2_d").prop("disabled",true);
  $("#pymt_details_1_a").focus();
});
$("#pymt_details_2").click(function() {
  $("#pymt_details_1_a").prop("disabled",true);
  $("#pymt_details_1_b").prop("disabled",true);
  $("#pymt_details_2_a").prop("disabled",false);
  $("#pymt_details_2_b").prop("disabled",false);
  $("#pymt_details_2_c").prop("disabled",false);
  $("#pymt_details_2_d").prop("disabled",false);
  $("#pymt_details_2_a").focus();
});
```

I have commented out parts of this code trying to get to the issue and I can't get it to run using the first selection no matter what.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Side note: any time you find yourself writing repetetive, almost identical code, assume there's a better way. You could massively reduce that JS with a simple array/loop.

Comment: the problem is not what you added in the question - can you add form submission part of jQuery code ?

Comment: Please review [ask] and [edit] your question to include the code we need to be able to see the problem in [MRE], so we can see where the problem is and be able to help!

Comment: Please Add your code on JsFiddle. so another people can see entire problem. thanks

Comment: @Mitya I see that and have tried to find an answer to how to do that in a loop, but haven't been able to find anything, Although I admit this is secondary to a much larger project I am involved in and new to using JavaScript.  Can you point me to a resource? I'd love to be able to do this better.